# textViews not appearing

Tags: android, eclipse

In the android preview screen in eclipse, I see the following: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63060352/379d2a92a0b1f8300d25ff15bf5bcbae.png

But when I run the app on my phone, the "Feedback" and "Suggestions or feedback? Let us know." textViews are not there, but the others are. I am confused why these aren't showing when I run the app on my phone and on the emulator.

Here's my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/info_screen_high"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".InfomenuActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="154dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/star_rating_medium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="149dp"
    android:text="Rate It"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="32sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Rate this app in the market!"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textColor="#B6B6B4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Tell a friend"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="29dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Spread the word about the app!"
    android:textColor="#B6B6B4"
    android:textSize="17dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="285dp"
    android:text="Feedback"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="29dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="Suggestions or feedback? Let us know."
    android:textColor="#B6B6B4"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If anyone could help me out, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think the `textview`s are lost under the screen. I believe if you wrap your `RelativeLayout` in a `ScrollView` then you should be able to see the `TextView`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have android:layout_marginTop="285dp" in the textView5, is too much! You can put something like 30dp and it is going to work

Comment: When I put 30dp, the text views are way to high up, that's why I put 285, it fits perfectly.

Comment: Ok. I suggested that because in eclipse not showing me these TextvView. Do you try removing the line android: layout_below = "@ + id/textView4 ?? If I delete that line I can see those text in eclipse.

Comment: Ok, I removed the "android:layout_below="'+id/textView4" and then repositioned it and it works great. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to remove these paddings, might be this problem.

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

can u show us a snapshot of this screen appearing in device.

Comment: I tried removing those paddings and the last textView's were still missing when I ran them sadly.